# NHibernate - Transforming to class within a class?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I keep getting an annoying error with NHibernate when I try to transform returned data from SQL to a class with classes inside. Lets say I these classes.

```
[DataContract()]
public class Person {
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Dog Dog { get; set; }
}
[DataContract()]
public class Dog {
    [DataMember]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And I have this SQL-query.

```
SELECT
    p_name AS 'Name',
    p_dog_age AS 'Dog.Age'
FROM People WHERE p_name = 'Foo';
```

And to transform this into a Person class I

```
var person = Session.CreateSQLQuery(Sql.GetPerson)
                .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(Person)))
                .Future<Person>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Whenever I do this, I get the following error

```
An exception of type 'NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException' occurred in NHibernate.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Complaining that it can't find the property of Dog.Age and that it does not have a setter property. I know it should be possible to do this but I can't figure it out.

I know that the values that are returned from the SQL query are not null.

Comment: I saw your solution and it looks good. But is it not possible to do it without extending the transformer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

After looking around and trying some different approaches I came up with this.

```
private void doStuff(){
    var listOfRows = Session.CreateSQLQuery(Sql.GetPerson)
        .List();

    var listOfPersonRows = new List<Person>();

    if (listOfRows.Count != 0)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < listOfRows.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = (object[])listOfRows[i];
            listOfPersonRows.Add(ConvertToRow(item));
        }
    }
}

private Person ConvertToRow(object[] item)
{
    var personRow = new Person();

    personRow.Name = (string)item[0];
    personRow.Dog.Age = (int)item[1];


    return personRow;
}
```

This way I still only have to query the database once instead of multiple times.

Comment: Nhibernate is really good for hiding clunky data readers and array data mapping. Have a look at my answer, maybe it'll help you!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to map a component. 
Using FluentNHibernate:

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{ 
    public PersonMap() 
    {
        Table("Person");
        Id(p => p.Id, "Id").GeneratedBy.Native().Not.Nullable();
        Map(p => p.Name, "Name").Length(255).Not.Nullable();

        Component(p => p.Dog, d =>
        {
            d.Map(dog => dog.Name, "DogName").Not.Nullable();
            d.Map(dog => dog.Age, "DogAge").Not.Nullable();
        }
    }    
}
```

you'd need a table with 4 columns for this:

- id
- name (person's name)
- dogname (the person's dog's name)
- dogage (the person's dog's age)

but - what if a person has two dogs? or no dogs?

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{ 
    public PersonMap() 
    {
        Table("Person");
        Id(p => p.Id, "Id").GeneratedBy.Native().Not.Nullable();

        References(p => p.Dog, "Dog").Nullable();
    }
}

public class DogMap : ClassMap<Dog>
{
    Map(d => d.Id, "Id").GeneratedBy.Native();

    References(p => p.Person, "Person").Nullable();
    Map(d => d.Name, "Name").Not.Nullable();
    Map(d => d.Age, "Age").Not.Nullable();
    }    
}
```

this needs two tables and would benefit from a couple of foreign keys referencing Id's.

using NHibernate's Linq implementation you can directly query the dog's name and age from a person:

```
var dog = 
   _session.Query<Person>()
           .Where(p => p.Name == "Charlie Brown")
           .Where(p => p.Dog.Name == "Snoopy")
           .Select(p => p.Dog)
           .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: We aren't using FluentNHibernate or mapping at all. So that's unfortunately not a solution. Otherwise referencing like that would definetly have been the solution.